# How do I log information a user has submitted to a form in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

So. I have a working code for defining a user set variable.
Currently, I use the `var data= prompt("prompt", "default entry")`
for cleanliness sake.
Is there a way I could log this variable string to a .txt file or some information on my server so I could access the user's input?

This is for a Linux Based Web Server, but I do file management remotely through an FTP Server on Windows.

I am inexperienced in JavaScript, so I could be missing a glaring issue.

However, I have looked through much of Google, but I have not experienced any results with their methods.

No error messages come up on my console, on either end, with any of the methods I have tried. A couple of methods remove the prompt entirely. 
No file has shown up with any of the methods I've tried so far.

Comment: If you want to log to a file, you won't be able to do this through client-side code alone. From the client, you will need to send the information to the server (e.g. form post or AJAX). Then, on the server side, you will need code to receive this value and write to the log file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be running some kind of server side application, this is a topic way out of range for a StackOverflow question as you could choose a huge range of different technologies from Node.JS, ASP.NET Web API, Java, PHP and a huge list more.

One quick way I would recommend is read up on Node.js, create an end point expecting a post and just put an action on your form pointing to the end point and then log the contents of the post to a text file.

The proper solution would involve setting up a database but is way more involved.